# Php pass provider - sandboxed and load balanced across multiple servers

Tags: php, google-app-engine, heroku, amazon-web-services, paas

I was wondering if any one can list the alternatives to google app engine to run php as a paas in the same sandboxed way.

It is my understanding that gae distributes your app across many servers (these servers are shared with other apps). This makes your app highly scalable (a customer in their google io demo said they ran 800 concurrent requests) and efficient (there is no virtual machine sitting idel or at non full capacity.

Unfortunately gae is unsuitable for my use case because (as of my understanding) :

- there is a limit of 10 apps (each customer of mine would require their own app).
- there is no API to deploy a new application, this has to be done via their GUI console and cannot be automated

I understand that Heroku can run php in sandboxed and routed environment. However does it allow unlimited apps? And a command line or API to create them? Does it support apc?

What are some other good alternatives which run php across multiple shared servers automatically scaling and routing requests?

If there are no other options how much effort would it be to build myself on Aws for example?

Sorry if this question is to open ended.

Comment: What about Pagodabox?

Comment: Thanks I had a look at Pagodabox but I wasnt clear how it worked.

Comment: Pagodabox is working on an auto-scale feature (but I do believe that if you have multiple web instances they will loadbalance them as you would expect). But the plus for you is that it uses GIT or FTP for deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are wrong on a number of counts.

You said

> **there is a limit of 10 apps (each customer of mine would require their own app).**

You can request limit increases.

In addition appengine supports multitenancy (namespaces) (not sure of the current support for appengine, but its there in python, java, and go)

If that model doesn't suit, then the customer can create the instance, and give you developer/admin rights.

> **there is no API to deploy a new application, this has to be done via their GUI console and cannot be automated**

appcfg is a command line tool and can be automated

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I will need to look into multitenancy. Thanks!